# What is wrong with this for loop in my script?

Tags: windows-10, batch

```
K:\bin>type get_date_without_space.bat
SET DATE_WITH_SPACE=%DATE%
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-2" %I IN ("%DATE_WITH_SPACE%") DO SET DATE_WITHOUT_SPACE=%I_%J
ECHO %DATE_WITHOUT_SPACE%
```

This doesn't work. Why?

```
K:\bin>get_date_without_space.bat
K:\bin>SET DATE_WITH_SPACE=Fri 11/16/2018
DATE_WITH_SPACEI_J was unexpected at this time.

K:\bin>FOR /F "TOKENS=1-2" DATE_WITH_SPACEI_J
K:\bin>
```

Comment: To replace your space , simply use string substitution `Echo %date: =_%`

Comment: This works. But can you give me the syntax of the FOR statement, in order to do the job? I still don't find the correct statement.

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, double the percent signs of the for meta variables `%%I` and `%%J` See http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Comment: run `for /?` and read it's output

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-2" %%I IN ("%DATE_WITH_SPACE%") DO SET DATE_WITHOUT_SPACE=%%I_%%J
```

The meta variables are I and J and the original code used `%I` and `%J` instead of `%%I` and `%%J`.

Comment: If you need to post additional information to your question, please edit it to do so. But posting this as an answer? Nope.

Comment: This is not additional information to be added to the question;  this ***is*** the answer (albeit woefully terse).

Comment: @Scott I am utterly unable to understand how this is an answer.

Comment: @JakeGould: The problem was that the OP was using `%I` and `%J` in a BAT file.  The answer (shown above) is to use `%%I` and `%%J` instead of `%I` and `%J`. (I *did* say that it was woefully terse.)

Comment: @Scott Makes sense. Edited to add that bit of info.